# RxJava switchMap doesn't cancel the previous Request

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, okhttp

I am developing an Android app using Kotlin, OkHttp, RxJava2.

I am trying to make an auto searching.

When user input a character, searching it.

```
override fun search(subject: PublishSubject<String>) {
    disposable.add(
            subject.debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .switchMap { keyword ->
                        search(keyword)
                    }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({ response ->
                        // using the response
                    }, {
                        it.printStackTrace()
                    })
    )
}
```

And the search function:

```
    fun search(keyword: String): Observable<String> {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(RequestBody.create(contentType, xmlBody(keyword)))
            .build()

        return Observable.fromCallable {
            val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()
            response.body()?.string()
        }
    }
```

I like "Retrofit", but in my case, I should use XML.
I tried to use Retrofit with SimpleXMLConverter, but it is not fit this project.
So I am using "OkHttp".
But the upper code throws "InterruptedIOException".

The first call is ok.
But Exception occurs when a next search request is received while the first request is being processed.

How should I fix this?

I think, the switchMap should cancel the previous Request, but it doesn't.

Comment: `search()` is blocking the thread the `switchMap` works on so it can't be cancelled. Apply `subscribeOn` directly to that `fromCallable`.

Comment: when you call `OkHttpClient().newCall(request)` it returns [`Call`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.html) instance, that has special method [`cancel`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.html#cancel--). In that way, it'll be better to use `Observable.create()` and call `Call#cancel()` after onDispose was happened

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You have set the schedulers wrong.

You need to:

```
override fun search(subject: PublishSubject<String>) {
disposable.add(
        subject.debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .switchMap { keyword ->
                    search(keyword).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                }

                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ response ->
                    // using the response
                }, {
                    it.printStackTrace()
                })
)
```

}

Note that the background scheduler needs to be set directly in the search completable, not on the chain after `switchmap`.
This is to execute the search in a chain other than the main chain, otherwise the whole chain will be blocked and `swichmap` will seem to have no effect, as it will cancel the search only once this has completed naturally.